# Sql Server Return Max date and Date Nearest to and Greater than Max Date

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, date

I have a table with many IDs with two potential "Types" and many dates associated with each ID and "Type." I want to select the ID, latest date for "Type" A and the closest date for "Type" B that is greater than type A.

```
Sample Table        
ID  Type    Date
1   A   1/5/2013
1   A   1/10/2013
1   B   1/1/2013
2   A   2/10/2013
2   A   2/9/2013
2   B   2/15/2013
2   B   2/20/2013
3   A   3/15/2013
3   B   3/10/2013
3   B   3/20/2013
```

Desired Result

```
ID  Date A  Date B
2   2/10/2013   2/15/2013
3   3/15/2013   3/20/2013
```

ID 1 is left off because it does not satisfy the condition B > Max(typeA) {1/10/13}
ID 2 equals max(typeA) {2/10/13 vs 2/9/13} and Date B {2/15/13} is greater than Date A and the closest of the two dates that meet that condition.
ID 3 equals only A entry and closest B entry {3/20/13} that is greater than Date A

I've tried several min, max, and row/partition iterations but the results have left off several qualifying entries. Using Sql Server 2008 V 10. Any help would greatly be appreciated

Answer (score 4):

Assuming SQL Server 2005+, you can use this:

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT [ID],
           [Type],
           [Date],
           RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY [ID] ORDER BY [Date] DESC)
    FROM YourTable
    WHERE [Type] = 'A'
)
SELECT A.[ID], 
       A.[Date] [Date A],
       B.[Date] [Date B]
FROM (SELECT *
      FROM CTE
      WHERE RN = 1) A
CROSS APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 [Date]
             FROM YourTable
             WHERE [Type] = 'B'
             AND [ID] = A.[ID]
             AND [Date] > A.[Date]
             ORDER BY [Date]) B
```

The results are:

```
╔════╦═════════════════════════════════╦═════════════════════════════════╗
║ ID ║             DATE A              ║             DATE B              ║
╠════╬═════════════════════════════════╬═════════════════════════════════╣
║  2 ║ February, 10 2013 00:00:00+0000 ║ February, 15 2013 00:00:00+0000 ║
║  3 ║ March, 15 2013 00:00:00+0000    ║ March, 20 2013 00:00:00+0000    ║
╚════╩═════════════════════════════════╩═════════════════════════════════╝
```

And [**here is**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a29817/4) an sqlfiddle for you to try.

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

```
SELECT ID, A_Date, B_Date
FROM (
    SELECT a.ID,a.Date 'A_Date', b.Date 'B_Date', ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY a.ID ORDER BY DATEDIFF(day,a.Date,b.Date))'RowRank'
    FROM (SELECT ID,Type, MAX(Date)'Date'
          FROM Table1
          WHERE Type = 'A'
          GROUP BY ID,Type
          )a
    JOIN Table1 b
      ON a.ID = b.ID
      AND a.Type <> b.Type
      AND a.Date < b.Date
  )sub
WHERE RowRank = 1
```

Demo: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/bc246/8/0)